Is there anything in particular VS Is there anything particular


Is there anything in particular?
Is there anything particular?


Sentence #1 is commonly seen and acceptable, but it seems sentence #2 is not.
For sentence #2, in reality, most people use " Is there anything special" instead.
I wonder why sentence #2 is not favoured and whether it is grammatically correct.

They mean slightly different things, but "Is there anything particular?" is fine - there are more examples where it's qualified, such as "Is there anything particular you want?", "Is there anything particular I should know about this game before buying it?"

You can get more useful answers by giving examples with a bit more context. Btw see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anything+particular%2Canything+in+particular&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 : "anything particular" was actually more common in the 19th century.
